# Entity Framework - Update entity with child properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity

I have an entity that has one child and I need to update it, but, in the TryUpdateModel  method, it does not accept an strong typed object (accepts only a FormCollection), and when I try to update it, I get the following error.

{"A relationship is being added or deleted from an AssociationSet 'FK__SG_Usuari__ID_Si__534D60F1'. With cardinality constraints, a corresponding 'SG_Usuario' must also be added or deleted."}

The problem is that I can't load in the formcollection the child property, only an id, but not the entire object.

Comment: Please show the code that causes the problem, say if it happens at runtime or design time, and post the complete exception, with all InnerException and stack traces. Post the results of ex.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

You can directly click update from model in entity framework and it will automatically update the enitty with all the relationship

Answer (score 0):

the "create" statement is like this:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection  form)
    {

      Usuario usuario = new Usuario
             {
                 NomeUsuario = form["Usuario.NomeUsuario"],
                 IdeUsuario = form["Usuario.IdeUsuario"],
                 NumRegistroRM = form["Usuario.NumRegistroRM"],
                 SenUsuario = form["Usuario.SenUsuario"],
                 SituacaoUsuario = this.SituacaoUsuarioService.GetSituacaoUsuario(x => x.ID_SituacaoUsuario == Convert.ToInt32(form["Usuario.SituacaoUsuario"]// note that i have to retrieive the entire object... the "child"

             };

      this.UsuarioService.AddUsuario(usuario);
     }
```

the edit statement should be like this:

```
 TryUpdateModel(a, "Usuario", this.GetUsuarioWhiteList(), form.ToValueProvider()); // but the form contains only the id and I can't load the child in it nor pass the object.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently and I managed to solve it when I changed the cardinality ratios for my foreign keys in the child table from 1:many to 0..1:many in the Entity Designer and it worked fine.